# Prevent PostGIS Topology from splitting edges on line insert

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, topology

I'm dealing with a large amount of road data represented with PostGIS Topology types. Anytime I add an edge over another edge, the edge is automatically split and a new node is created at the intersection of the two lines. This creates a problem when I have roads that overlap other roads at bridges or underpasses. Is it possible to prevent edges from automatically being split when inserting an edge using `TopoGeo_AddLineString`? Or is this an incorrect usage of Topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out, PostGIS Topology supports a z-index. If you want to prevent new lines from splitting other lines in the topology, they need to have different z-indexes. The `CreateTopology` function has a parameter `hasz` that allows support for this but it is false by default.

http://postgis.net/docs/CreateTopology.html

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS Topology is not good for modeling road networks. The  ISO/IEC 13249-3 (SQL/MM) standard has a different API for that (Network Topology) which is not implemented in PostGIS yet.

But, if it may help, it's now implemented in spatialite:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=topo-intro

Comment: Note to anonymous moderator: I think this poster can be considered a "reliable source" !