# PostGIS topology for merging lines?

Tags: postgis, postgis-topology

I know PostGIS Topology supports [splitting road edges](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122636) while creating a network.

I was wondering if PostgIS topology can do the opposite and merge two lines?

Does it support merging two consecutive road segments that touch each other at a common (degree-2) node?